SQL getting the data by timestamp interval
I have a table that list status of works based on date.
For example:



date from
date to
Status




2023-01-01
2023-01-02
In progress


2023-01-02
2023-01-03
In progress


2023-01-03
2023-01-04
No electricty


2023-01-04
2023-01-05
In progress



I would like to summarize the table to the following:



date from
date to
Status




2023-01-01
2023-01-03
In progress


2023-01-03
2023-01-04
No electricty


2023-01-04
2023-01-05
In progress



I have tried using max/min over the columns, but I get back is the following:



date from
date to
Status




2023-01-01
2023-01-05
In progress


2023-01-03
2023-01-04
No electricty



Which is not correct.
Anyone an idea of how can I write my query to obtain my result ?

Search for  the Gaps and Islands Problem. A lot of solutions here.

This is a gaps and islands problem in disguise.  We can try using the difference in row numbers method here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_from) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY date_from) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MIN(date_from) AS date_from,
    MAX(date_to) AS date_to,
    Status
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Status,
    (rn1 - rn2);


I didn't know this problem has a name, thanks for pointing it out!
